# Creating a HLSL shader that simply flips X coordinate?

Tags: shader, hlsl

I am trying to find a mirror shader for MPC-HC. Would make old known videos feel slightly more fresh, as long as it doesn't have a lot of writing in it..

All I could find was FlipY.hlsl that flips the wrong coordinate (upside down) to be used for ceiling mounted projectors I guess. I am looking to modify this to flip the X coordinate instead but this code is unknown to me.

```
sampler s0 : register(s0);
float4 p0 : register(c0);
float4 p1 : register(c1);

#define width (p0[0])
#define height (p0[1])
#define counter (p0[2])
#define clock (p0[3])
#define one_over_width (p1[0])
#define one_over_height (p1[1])

float4 main(float2 tex : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR
{   
  float2 pnt;
    pnt.x=tex.x;
    pnt.y=1.0-tex.y;
    float4 c0 = tex2D(s0, pnt);      
    return c0;
}
```

Please help me understand what to do here.

Comment: I've only very briefly worked with hlsl, but seems to me `pnt.y = 1.0-tex.y` is where the flipping happens. `pnt.x = 1.0 - tex.x` makes sense to me. (`x` and `y` are in UV coords which range from 0-1)

Comment: Works nicely! Thanks.